# Can we debug classes present in rt.jar?

Tags: java

I have atteched the source file to project. I want to debug a method of say ArrayList. I placed a breakpoint also in that method but on debugging it gives error -unable to install breakpoint in eclipse due to missing line number attributes.Its a desktop application.

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing? I really doubt your problem is within the inner functionality of JDK but something on your code, unless it is for learning purposes.

Comment: I am doing it for learning process only. From main method of my class I am invoking the put() method of HashMap. I was trying to check the implementation easily by bebugging

Answer (score 0):

Use the JDK system library instead of the JRE, the latter isn't compiled with the necessary debugging information.